# ng-show not working on returned function value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

the logic is simple. Show the link when there is at least one checkbox checked. I do it within the calculate checkbox function.

JS

```
  $scope.calculateChecked = function() {
      var count = 0;
      angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value) {
        if(value.checked)
          count++;
      });
          if(count !=0){
            return count;
        }else{
            return "null";
        }
   };
```

html

```
 <a ng-show="{calculateChecked()}!='null'" ng-click="getlinks()"><p ng-show="loader==false" class="newtopic">Open {{calculateChecked()}} Topic</p></a>
```

I expect this work `ng-show="{calculateChecked()}!='null'"`but it doesn't

Comment: `ng-show="calculateChecked()!='null'"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the braces in `ng-show`

```
<a ng-show="calculateChecked() != 'null'" ng-click="getlinks()"><p ng-show="loader==false" class="newtopic">Open {{calculateChecked()}} Topic</p></a>
```

Comment: In this case null should be in quotes because it is returned from the function as a string.

Comment: I had made the change immediately after I answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the angled braces around the function call:

ng-show="calculateChecked()!='null'"